# python vscode environment variables not available

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have attempted to follow the directions for environment variables in my project and thought I was doing the correct thing but it does not appear to be working when debugging my python code in vscode.

I have a launch.json for a project in .vscode/

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/dev.env"
        }
    ]
}
```

and a dev.env file in my project root

```
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
PASSWORD=abc123
DEBUG_SSO=user.name
CELERY_DEBUG=True
SEND_MAIL=True
```

when I hit a breakpoint and do "os.getenv('PASSWORD')" it returns None, even though the variable is set in dev.env.

Any idea what is wrong with this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the relative path being unrecognized.
Add this line to the file "launch.json" : "cwd": "${fileDirname}"